# Setting a TSource value to a String

Tags: c#, .net, type-conversion

I need to manipulate a `TSource` variable.

//Code:

```
 private static DataTable ToDataTable<TSource>(this IList<TSource> data)
  {
          foreach (TSource item in data)
            {
                switch (item.ToString())
                 {
                    case "Name":
                        item = "John";  //Error here
                        break;
                 }
            }
  }
```

**Error:**

```
Cannot implicitly convert type string to TSource.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: How this code will compile? you cannot assign to item because it is inside foreach

Comment: Why do you want set item to string? If you want use item as a string why using Generic class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As TSource is generic type, you cannot ensure that the conversion to `string` will be valid, so `item = "John";` always show you a compilation error.

I think you have a couple of possibilities:

- You can assume that the collection is not of `TSource` type and set as `IList<string>`.
- You can define a base type that can be explicitly assigned from string.

In example:

```
internal class StringConvertible
{
    public static implicit operator string(StringConvertible value)
    {
        return value.StringValue;
    }

    public static implicit operator StringConvertible(string value)
    {
        return new StringConvertible
        {
            StringValue = value
        };
    }

    public virtual string StringValue { get; set; }
}

// ...

private static DataTable ToDataTable<TSource>(this IList<TSource> data)
{
    for (int index = 0; index < data.Count; index++)
    {
        if (!typeof(TSource).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(StringConvertible)))
        {
            continue;
        }

        StringConvertible value = data[index] as StringConvertible;
        switch (value)
        {
            case "Name":
                value.StringValue = "John";
                break;
        }     
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: There are at least two errors: `StringConvertible value = (StringConvertible)(object)item;` you need an intermediate cast to object, or you must use `StringConvertible value = item as StringConvertible`. The second one, more important, is that you can't `return new StringConvertible(value)`, because `StringConvertible` is an abstract class, and then you really want to create a `TSource`.

Comment: Ops! True... Example deleted!

Comment: Better an example with a virtual abstract getter/setter (public abstract string StringValue { get; set; }). And modifying an item that is being enumerated is something that must be done "with caution"

Answer (score 2):

Another option in addition to those pointed out by HuorSwords might be passing a custom converting function into ToDataTable, like this:

```
private static DataTable ToDataTable<TSource>(this IList<TSource> data, Func<string, TSource> itemFromString)
  {
          foreach (TSource item in data)
            {
                switch (item.ToString())
                 {
                    case "Name":
                        item = itemFromString("John");
                        break;
                 }
            }
  }
```